# Is there a way to know if the current process holds a specific file lock?

Tags: winapi

We have a serie of applications running on windows that uses file locking for protecting concurrent access to their data (shared files on network drive).

Sometimes, it seems one of these process fails to release one of these locks and everything freezes until the process is killed. Finding out who holds that lock is not always trivial (needs an admin to go on the file server and check network open files, go one workstation, find process and kill it).

We have a message queue system between the applications that is serviced by a background thread so, in theory, it would be possible to send out a message to every process asking them if they hold a lock to a specific file and if they do, mybe take an action like kill the process if the lock is held longer than a few seconds)

So, the question is: is there a way for a thread to know if a different thread of the same process holds a lock (LockFile) against a given file?

Comment: Did you check if WinDbg can show a list of lock holders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a API to query this but a process can query itself with the `LockFileEx` function:

> A shared lock can overlap an exclusive lock **if both locks were created using the same file handle**. When a shared lock overlaps an exclusive lock, the only possible access is a read by the owner of the locks.

The other thread could query and see if it can get shared access.

---

If you control the file format you could write the computer name and process id to the start of the file every time you take the lock. File memory mappings can view the file contents even while it is locked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anders. Unfortunately, there is no way for me to obtain the original handle and maintaining a list of all locks in a central DB would kill performances.